# Texture don't look good compared to Substance Painter. What's wrong on my end?

Tags: texturing, uv

I made a high poly jacket and used Smart UV Project in Blender combined with Triplanar texturing in Substance and it gave me a good enough result for what I needed. Nonetheless, why does it look worse in Cycles compared to Substance? I've attached my [Blender](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZDSfN_VeKDwL2055pwKfNS7Gr33jd7C8/view?usp=sharing) and my [Substance](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mUCVYyyPfEyrwKR5hZOSIN6d1j4pDHJQ/view?usp=sharing) files for you to peruse. Here are some screenshots of what I mean and settings. Thanks for any help! As a side note, toggling with normals' strength didn't help much in Blender (I may just be bad at it).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: One thing to have under consideration is that Blender uses Open GL not Direct X for the normal maps, and you are exporting Direct X normal into Blender. Another thing is the light setup.

Comment: The lighting is something I kept in the back of my head and will definitely iterate more on for better results. However, I did not think/know much about the Direct X and Open GL issue. I'm gonna play around with that.

Comment: Hey Emir, so I did the node setup you showed. I guess while it does the switching to Open GL. I'm still curious why I'm not getting that beautiful, slightly "puffy" or "cushion-y" feeling with the knitted pattern in my shoulder areas of the jacket like how it looks in Substance. Adjusting normals and displacement helps sliiightly, but still looks weird compared to substance. Added natural sun setting to really show the texture. https://i.imgur.com/pL0cW53.jpg

Comment: Huzzah! I fixed it. I exported as Open GL from Substance and plugged in the Material_Normal_OpenGL instead of the Material_Normal and it solved literally everything! Thanks for all your help! You can see the difference here: https://i.imgur.com/vgpOBIh.jpg

Comment: @majiinakuma feel free to post this as an answer, and after a couple of days you can accept it as the solution

Comment: done and done! For clarity, any reason I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer?

Comment: @majiinakuma probably just to stop people from spamming self-answers, it's kind of annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huzzah! I fixed it. I exported as Open GL from Substance and plugged in the Material_Normal_OpenGL instead of the Material_Normal and it solved literally everything! Thanks for all your help! You can see the difference here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want use the textures that you already have, you could use the following node setup to "convert your normals to Open GL" by connecting a separate XYZ, invert the Y, combining the X, NEW Y and Z to the normal map node
and this is a raw result with an HDRI (you need to tweek that to make it better).

But remember that the best option is to import a proper Normal for Open GL.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right... Fixed