# Normal and height maps cannot be displayed

Tags: texturing

I use substance painter to make texture, then link to blender.
However, the normal and height maps can't display.
the blue one is the curtain(right) I made. it looks so flat when I link the height map(left)
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texture don't look good compared to Substance Painter. What's wrong on my end?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238391/texture-dont-look-good-compared-to-substance-painter-whats-wrong-on-my-end)

Comment: Hello, please pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/