# Strange behavior of textures imported from substance painter

Tags: import

I made a couple of models to try substance painter and it's alright until I'm importing it back into blender, models appear to be glossy, they shouldn't, and there are also these dark spots that should not be there.

[image: the problem]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack the images and share the file?

Comment: @moonboots Okay, I uploaded the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texture don't look good compared to Substance Painter. What's wrong on my end?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238391/texture-dont-look-good-compared-to-substance-painter-whats-wrong-on-my-end)

Comment: @Emir, it does not, a man in the question did that I already done

Comment: does switching the Image Texture (with your normal map) from sRGB to Non-Color fix your problem?

Comment: @moonboots, oh, it does, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the *Image Texture* with your normal map from *sRGB* to *Non-Color*:

[image]